# How to keep Console Window open after execution?

Tags: c#, windows, batch-file, cmd

It's a little bit complicated problem. I have tried probably everything and still no working. I run WinForm application from I run CMD and next run another app(console application) on cmd. It's working on `/c START xyz` but when app finished CMD always is closing. I want to pause this window.

```
ProcessStartInfo processInfo = new ProcessStartInfo {
    FileName = "cmd.exe",
    WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(YourApplicationPath),
    Arguments = "/K START " + cmdparametr,
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    CreateNoWindow = false,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal,
};

Process p = new Process {
    StartInfo = processInfo
};
p.Start();

int ExitCode;
p.WaitForExit();

// *** Read the streams ***
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

ExitCode = p.ExitCode;

MessageBox.Show("output>>" + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(output) ? "(none)" : output));
MessageBox.Show("error>>" + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(error) ? "(none)" : error));
MessageBox.Show("ExitCode: " + ExitCode.ToString(), "ExecuteCommand");
p.Close();
```

`ReadStream` is working when I add argument: `START /b` but I think it's not important. 
`WaitForExit()` doesn't work.

Is it possible to pause application through command maybe like this: 
`/k start xyz.exe & PAUSE`?

---

My app is console application!

Comment: Have you tried just appending `& pause` to the end of your command as your question notes? Perhaps related - is there any reason you are redirecting input?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the `pause`-command inside C# if you want:
I use it as follows:

**Solution №1:**

```
//optional: Console.WriteLine("Press any key ...");
Console.ReadLine(true);
```

**Solution №2:** *(Uses P/Invoke)*

```
// somewhere in your class
[DllImport("msvcrt.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl, SetLastError=true)]
public static extern int system(string command);

public static int Main(string[] argv)
{
    // your code


    system("pause"); // will automaticly print the localized string and wait for any user key to be pressed
    return 0;
}
```

---

**EDIT**: you can create a temporary batch file dynamically and execute it, for example:

```
string bat_path = "%temp%/temporary_file.bat";
string command = "command to be executed incl. arguments";

using (FileStream fs = new FileStream(bat_path, FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.Read))
using (StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.Default))
{
    sw.WriteLine("@echo off");
    sw.WriteLine(command);
    sw.WriteLine("PAUSE");
}

ProcessStartInfo psi = new ProcessStartInfo() {
    WorkingDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(YourApplicationPath),
    RedirectStandardOutput = true,
    RedirectStandardInput = true,
    RedirectStandardError = true,
    CreateNoWindow = false,
    UseShellExecute = false,
    WindowStyle = System.Diagnostics.ProcessWindowStyle.Normal
};

Process p = new Process() {
    StartInfo = psi;
};
p.Start();

int ExitCode;
p.WaitForExit();

// *** Read the streams ***
string output = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
string error = p.StandardError.ReadToEnd();

ExitCode = p.ExitCode;

MessageBox.Show("output>>" + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(output) ? "(none)" : output));
MessageBox.Show("error>>" + (String.IsNullOrEmpty(error) ? "(none)" : error));
MessageBox.Show("ExitCode: " + ExitCode.ToString(), "ExecuteCommand");
p.Close();

File.Delete(bat_path);
```

Comment: It's Windows forms application, not Console Application.

Comment: Thank you!! This is it what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

For preventing the close of a Console Application you could use :

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

It would wait for  for any key and would not close immediately.

Comment: Cannot read keys when either application does not have a console or when console input has been redirected from a file. Try Console.Read.

Comment: doesn't work... If I use only `/c START xyz` I get one window and when it finished it close window.

Answer (score 1):

Do not include `START` command, use something like this

```
processInfo.Arguments = "/K " + your_console_app_exe_path_and_args;
```

Make sure to enclose with double quotes where needed.

Comment: Nope, without parameter `START` I haven't seen any result of console application.

Comment: That's because you are redirecting the output of your console app.